# Arduino - Emitindo Sinal Infravermelho

Tags: arduino

Estou tentando ligar e desligar um projetor da Sony com Arduíno, já consegui capturar o código enviado pelo controle. Porém ao transmitir esse sinal para o projetor, não acontece nada. Por favor alguem pode ajudar? 
Esse é o código que estou utilizando:

```
#include <boarddefs.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
}

void loop() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    irsend.sendSony(0x542A, 32);
    delay(40);
}

delay(5000); //5 segundos

}
```

Também já tentei enviar o RAW, ficou assim:

```
#include <boarddefs.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
}

void loop() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{irsend.sendSony(160602400600115060060060012006006006001200550600600600600600600600600120060060060012005506006001200600600, 32);

    delay(40);
}

delay(5000); //5 segundos

}
```

Comment: Certificou-se que o LED infra-vermelho está realmente emitindo?

Comment: Sim, o  LED estava emitindo sinal. Obrigado pela ajuda, mas já resolvi o problema. Estavo enviando o código do controle de modo errado.
Aqui esta o código que funcionou:





#include <boarddefs.h>

#include <IRremote.h>

#include <IRremoteInt.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>


IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
}

void loop() 
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
  irsend.sendSony(0x542A, 15);
  delay(20);
 }
 delay(1000);
}